# Closure of a set in $l^2 $ in the weak topolgy

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

> In $l^2$, $\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ with $1 \leqslant m<n$ we define $e_{n,m}=e_m+me_n$ where $\{e_n\}$ is the usual Schauder basis of $l^2$ and $A=\{e_{m,n}|1 \leqslant m<n \}$.Prove that $0$ belong to the closure of $A$ in weak topology and there is not a sequence in $A$ which converges weakly to $0$

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That $0$ belongs to the closure of $A$ means that every neighborhood of $0$ contains some element from $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some hints: For the first part, you need to prove that for all $x_1,x_2, \ldots, x_k \in x \in l^2$ and for all $\epsilon >0$ there are $n,m$ such that
$$
 \lvert \langle x_i, e_{n,m} \rangle \rvert < \epsilon
$$for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. First try to find an $m$ such that $\lvert \langle x_i, e_m \rangle \rvert < \epsilon/2$ for all $1 \leq i \leq k$. Fix such an $m$, then try to find an $n$ such that $\lvert \langle x_i, e_n \rangle \rvert < \epsilon/(2m)$.

For the second part, note that a sequence $(x_n)$ in $l^2$ converges to zero if and only if $\lim_n \langle x_n, y \rangle =0$ for all $y \in l^2$. So if $e_{f(n), g(n)}$ is a sequence in $A$ converging to zero, this means that $$
\lim_n (y_{g(n)} + g(n) \cdot y_{f(n)}) =0
$$
for all $y \in l^2$.
I'm positive you can now find an $y \in l^2$ where this doesn't hold.

Comment: thank you for your help!

Comment: @RamizKaraeski You're welcome!